how do I /kill a certain ground item in Minecraft Bedrock?
In my Bedrock realm, I have a compass that, when dropped, teleports you to spawn, but you can easily delete stuff people dropped. I don't want that to happen, I just want to delete the compass - or does anyone have another method of teleporting people to spawn?

When asking a Minecraft commands question, please see our guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question, especially the part about "what you've tried so far", and edit the requested information to your post.

You also say you don't want the compass to be deleted, then say you do right after?
